# CSS3 animation when hover ends

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a div with some images in it. When I move the mouse over one of the images, I want it to grow, when I move the mouse out I want it to shrink again. I know that there isn't a mouseout ore something like that in CSS, so I put the reverse animation into the normal style of the images. Now my problem is, that when I load the site all images do the shrinking animation.

Is there a way to do this only with CSS or do I have to use Javascript?

My HTML:

```
<div id="picmen">
    <img src="/images/b1.png" />
    <img src="/images/b2.png" />
    <img src="/images/b3.png" />
    <img src="/images/b4.png" />
    <img src="/images/b5.png" />
    <img src="/images/b6.png" />
    <img src="/images/b7.png" />
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#picmen img {
    float: right;
    margin: 3px 1px 3px 1px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    animation: shrink 0.5s;
}

@keyframes shrink {
    from{ width: 60px; height: 60px; }
    to{ width: 50px; height: 50px; }
}

#picmen img:hover {
    animation: grow 0.5s; 
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

@keyframes grow {
    from{ width: 50px; height: 50px; }
    to{ width: 60px; height: 60px; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
transition-duration: 0.5s;
```

instead of creating `@keyframe` animations.

Your code would look like:

```
#picmen img {
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 1px 3px 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#picmen img:hover {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

If you want to add easing, you can use:

```
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

More information about `transition` css3 can be found on the [w3schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp).

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmadan/LqanJ/).

---

#### Why it works:

When you define and use an `@keyframe` animation, your code will run the animation every time it is seen.
A browser will read your code like this:

```
#picmen img{  //define all images inside 'picmen' div
    ...    //all of the basics (float, margin)
    height:50px; //set height to 50px (iff no further instructions about height follow)
    width:50px;  //set width to 50px (iff no further instructions about width follow)
    animation: shrink 0.5s;  //run an animation called shrink for 0.5 seconds 
                             //every time this state is entered
        --run animation called 'shrink'--
            @keyframes shrink {  //defines 'shrink'
                from{ width: 60px; height: 60px; }  //redefines starting width and height
                to{ width: 50px; height: 50px; }  //defines ending width and height
            }
        --end animation--
}  //end image definition
```

`transition`, will only make those changes on (as the name suggests) transitions.
The first time your images are loaded, they don't go through any state changes, thus no transition.